# error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/nameless-cliffs-57613.git'

Tags: git, heroku

I have created a new app in Heroku. 
[image]

Then I ran this in the command line

```
git init 
heroku create 
git add . 
git push -f heroku master
```

in the end I get this error:

```
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/nameless-cliffs-57613.git'
```

[image]

Can you please show me how to make this right. Thank you.

Comment: What does git remote show origin say? Please post the hook. Then People might be able to help...

Comment: There's probably a bunch of useful stuff _before_ the "push rejected" message. Take a close look at it.

Comment: @Christoph, I don't think that makes much sense on Heroku. The application just isn't building properly. OP needs to read the output more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error text, the pre-recieve hook is failing the push since you're attempting to push code that doesn't compile (i.e., probably has syntax errors). Just fix the code and push again.

Comment: I don't see any errors since it runs fine on my local host and builds successfully.

Comment: [Works for me but not at Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bheroku%5D+failed+to+compile+Node.js+app) is quite an often situation. Please show the full **text** of the error.